# Java web architecture advice

Tags: java, rest, websocket, architecture, restful-architecture

I have a specific architectural demand described bellow and I hope for any answer, all help more than welcome.

So, I have a public Java server that handles request from users (via HTTP/REST). Those requests should be (in currently unknown manner) sent to different local servers. The problem is those local servers don't have open any incoming ports so I can't send them any REST calls (from my public server).

Further, each user belongs to an organization and each organization has its local server so based on a user I should decide to which local server I should send requests. I was thinking about Websocket connection from a local server to public one so that my public server can send requests to local ones whenever it wants. Because I can't connect to a local server (no opened ports, no network visibility) it has to connect to me (local -> global).

I draw a simple picture describing how I imagined the architecture but it also has its problems; if I cluster my public server (make few instances) how will I be able to know which server holds a Websocket connection to a user? So when a user sends me a request I can't be sure that public server instance dealing with that REST call also has a Websocket for an organization to which local network I should forward a message...

[image: My architecture but with a problem of pairing users and websockets]

It's a bit hard to explain but I did my best. If you have any other architecture proposal totally different than this one or know how to solve my problem with pairing users with Websockets I'd be really thankful.

Comment: Three letters - [VPN](https://github.com/OpenVPN). Which is (essentially) what you are proposing to implement via websocket.

Comment: Well, the problem is that no modificatons are able on local servers network, so i can't open a port, put it behind a dyndns or connect in a VPN...

Comment: Can you use broker architecture e.g. ActiveMQ on public side, than local servers are consumers for the queues, lets say one local server one queue. On the public server side you produces requests on a different queues based on users.

Comment: Well that's an option that also crossed my mind but my system is real-time and messages from public server are supposed to immediately trigger an action on local server or throw an exception. I'm not sure if it's a fit for MQ, maybe it could be but I perceive MQ as an asynchronous system whose messages are put in a queue and might not get processed immediately, maybe I'm wrong?